# ASP.NET Core MvcOptions dependency injection without modified closure?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, closures

In my ASP.NET Core project, I currently inject an `IFilterMetadata` dependency into `MvcOptions` in the `ConfigureServices` method in the following way:

```
public override IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddProjectSpecificStuff();

    IExceptionFilter exceptionFilter = null;

    services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(exceptionFilter); });

    var provider = base.ConfigureServices(services);

    exceptionFilter = provider.GetService<IExceptionFilter>();

    return provider;
}
```

This works, but causes code analyzers such as ReSharper to complain about access to modified closure.

Is there an alternative to achieve the same dependency injection without using modified closure?

Comment: Your `IExceptionFilter` will be cached for the duration of the lifetime of the app domain (it's a singleton). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your filters have dependencies, just register them with the generic add method instead of passing an instance.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.AddService(typeof(IExceptionFilter));
    // ASP.NET Core 2.0
    //options.Filters.AddService<IExceptionFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.1.3.0, and the `FilterCollection` class in this assembly does not have an `Add<T>()` method. Nonetheless, I applied your idea by calling `options.Filters.AddService(typeof(IExceptionFilter));` and everything worked, without having to use modified closure!

Comment: Although I am staying away from adding a concrete type, to retain the benefits of dependency injection, such as having the ability to inject using a factory, to resolve dependency based on build configuration, to resolve dependency based on configuration at run time, etc. etc.

Comment: If you edit your answer to remove the concrete type, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the helpful answer! I asked a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45826530/1541820