# ASP.NET Core MvcJsonOptions dependency injection without modified closure?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, closures

(This question is similar to [ASP.NET Core MvcOptions dependency injection without modified closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45807507/1541820) However, I struggle to apply the solution of that question to this one.)

In my ASP.NET Core 1.1.3 project, I currently inject an `ITraceWriter` dependency into `MvcJsonOptions` in the `ConfigureServices` method in the following way:

```
public override IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddProjectSpecificStuff();

    ITraceWriter traceWriter = null;

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = traceWriter;
    });

    var provider = base.ConfigureServices(services);

    traceWriter = provider.GetService<ITraceWriter>();

    return provider;
}
```

This works, but causes code analyzers such as ReSharper to complain about access to modified closure.

Is there an alternative to achieve the same dependency injection without using modified closure?

Comment: Just inject your own `ITraceWriter`, surely?

Comment: Yes, doing `options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = new MyTraceWriter();` is definitely one way to go. I want to avoid it if there are other alternatives that allow me to assign an instance of an interface to `options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter`, so that there's flexibility to do things like dependency injection using factory, dependency resolution based on build configuration, dependency resolution based on runtime configuration, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely postpone the assignment to `.Configure` method, it **should** work.

```
public override IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddProjectSpecificStuff();

    ITraceWriter traceWriter = null;

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        ...
        // other options here
    });

    return base.ConfigureServices(services);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ITraceWriter traceWriter, IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = provider.GetService<ITraceWriter>();
    });
}
```

This will work for as long as your dependencies (like `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` and `ITraceWriter` are singletons.

#### Word of warning

However, this behavior may change in future, as some plans/ideas were on the ASP.NET Core GitHub issues, that the ASP.NET Core may change this to create an implicitly scoped context which is used during `.Configure`, it may or may not break the above code (if it ever comes).

But you may want consider to directly instantiate the `ITraceWriter` and pass it as instance to the IoC container, such as

```
ITraceWriter traceWriter = new TraceWriter(/* other dependencies */);
services.AddSingleton<ITraceWriter>(traceWriter);
```

It's okay to compose it in the composition root, as long as it's a singleton.

Or alternatively you choose this brute and somewhat ugly solution and instantiate `MvcJsonOptions` via factory method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>(provider => Options.Create(new MvcJsonOptions
{
    SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = provider.GetService<ITraceWriter>()
}));
```

Then it's pretty ugly (though you could hide that behind an extension method) and you may override defaults set by the mddleware/extension method.

Comment: Nice! The direct instantiation suggestion fits my situation really well because I'm mainly working with singletons. Does this imply that I have to do direct instantiation all the way up the dependency tree? For example:

    `IDependency1 dependency1 = new Dependency1():
    services.AddSingleton<IDependency1>(dependency1);
    IDependency2 dependency2 = new Dependency2(dependency1);
    services.AddSingleton<IDependency2>(dependency2);
    ITraceWriter traceWriter = new TraceWriter(dependency2);
    services.AddSingleton<ITraceWriter>(traceWriter);`

Or is there a simpler way?